# ServiceWorker is not updating, goes to skipwaiting in React app

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, service-worker

When I make a new production build of React app, new services worker installs but goes to skipwaiting state. So I have to hard reset cache on every build that is not good on live site.

I can't tell to every client, "please clear your cache to see latest". If I remove registerServiceWorker() from index file then build production do not detect my routes so it redirects to 404.

Comment: I don't use React, so I am not sure about the issue here, but can you clear the cache you are referring to as part of an automated release process?

Comment: can you check if you are caching the serviceWorker.js?

Comment: and, your http server should always answer the request with the index.html, instead of a 404. https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment#serving-apps-with-client-side-routing

Answer (score 0):

I used react-rewired-app boilerplate for my project and faced issue in that. Now I resolved that with a bunch of code in **config-overrides.js** file

```
config.plugins.forEach((obj) => {
  if (obj.config) {
    if (obj.config.clientsClaim) {
      obj.config.skipWaiting = true
    }
  }
});
```